# Get a substring before the first figure in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract all the text until the first figure that appears.
Let's say I have this kind of string `"Paris 01 Louvre"`. I would
like to have only `"Paris"` or if I've `"Neuilly sur Seine 03 bla blab"`
I want to extract `"Neuilly sur Seine"`.

I'm struggling with regex in javascript but I can't find the right formula.

Comment: `What have you tried so far` doesn't fit here as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Neuilly sur Seine 03 bla blab".match(/^\D+(?=\s)/);
// => Neuilly sur Seine
```

This answer also ensures trailing whitespace isn't captured.

Comment: It will only ensures 1 trailing space is not captured.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks again for your reactivity

Answer (score 1):

basic regular expression:

```
var re = /^([^\d]+)\s/;    
var str = "Neuilly sur Seine 03 bla blab";
console.log( str.match(re) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`^(.+?)\d`

That grabs everything before the first digit (`\d`). [Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?3170r).

Answer (score 0):

Anything but a number:

```
^[^0-9]*
```

- `^` is the start-of-line
- `[]` indicates a character class
- `^` inside the character class means "invert this class"
- `0-9` is the numbers 0 to 9, so `[^0-9]` means any character besides 0 to 9
- `*` is "zero or more" of the character/class which it follows

Answer (score 0):

This grabs anything that's not a digit from the beginning of the string.

```
s.match(/^\D*/)
```